# Zero-sum games where getting information helps the opponent more

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

You may know of the paper on the "Memory" game - sometimes the best strategy is turning known cards (here: https://www.math.kth.se/xComb/x1.pdf). Here is a simpler toy example: You and your opponent have to guess a time on the clock (4,8,12), you say "4" or "8" or "12" and the referee says "Yes" if correct, "Nein" if it's closer clockwise and "Njet" if anticlockwise. Clearly the 2nd player has an 1/3:2/3 advantage since he gets more information from the answer than you.
Do you have more references for games with this effect? Especially, can it be avoided to scan the whole game tree (for longer games like Memory) by computing a local entropy? At least approximatively? (For example, if the referree says only "yes" and "no", the remaining possibilities have 1:1 chance, which favors you again. So ask a question that spreads them out as equally as possible.)

Comment: Your example is similar to the situation in the Monty Hall problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem